# How to do a select with python lambda expressions

Tags: python

How to do the following using lambda expressions in Python?

```
  result = None
  for current in listOfObjects:
      if current.number == 5:
         result = current.files
         break
```

Comment: You only want the `.files` of the first occurrence of `.number` 5 ?

Comment: Why would you want to use lambda for this?

Comment: @PinkFluffyUnicorn yes, only the first occurence of number 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter` with a lambda expression if you need the selection criterion to be something dynamic:

```
list_of_stuff = [type('obj', (object,), {'number' : n, 'files': ['testa', 'testb']}) for n in range(10)]

result = next(filter(lambda x: x.number==5, list_of_stuff)).files
```

Here I'm just taking the first result like you. 
If you always have the same selection criterion, it could make sense to use a list comprehension instead:

```
result = next(x for x in list_of_stuff if x.number==5).files
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that it would make any sense to use lambda here, just for the sake of it:

```
next(filter(lambda x:x.number==5,listOfObjects)).files
```